# How to look if a pointer in a pointer map is not 0

Tags: c++, windows, dictionary, visual-studio-2005

I made a map, I need that map in another thread, so I made a pointer that points to my map and send it to the other thread. But when I want to look if the value in a map is not NULL (Pointer) I get an error.

This is a example codee:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int test = 1;

    map<int,void *> handle;
    map<int,void *> * handle2;

    handle[0] = &test;

    handle2 = &handle;


    if(*handle2[0])
    {
        cout << "Works\n";
    }

    system("Pause");


    return false;
}
```

This is the error I get:

error C2451: conditional expression of type 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' is illegal

How can I cheak for a 0 pointer in this case?

Comment: btw g++ error is `no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘** handle2’` which makes it clearer (at least to me) that it is an  operator priority problem... it's OT I know, but I feel always uncomfortable when I see a `system("pause")` in code, I would suggest you to find a way to feel it unnecessary (since its "need" comes just from the way you run your code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handle2` is a pointer to a map, so `handle2[0]` (equivalent to `*handle2`) is the map itself. As the error says, this can't be used as a conditional expression.

If you want to check whether `handle2` is null, just say `handle2`; for the element of the map with key 0, you want `(*handle2)[0]`.

Comment: It should be also noted that his case isn't thread safe, and he is using multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(*handle2[0])
```

One possibility:

```
if((*handle2)[0])
```

another (slightly cryptic for me):

```
if(handle2[0][0])
```